# I have 5:5 matrix of image elements on main QML form with Grid

Tags: image, resize, qml

What I want to implement is if user clicks on one of the images, it should take me to another QML page and on pressing ESC, it should go back to main QML file.

Also, if the user re-sizes the window, the images should arrange themselves according to the size of the window.

i.e. small images if window is shrunk and larger images if window is stretched.

Is this possible? If yes, how can I make sure that the icons would change their size on changing the size of the window and on clicking it would take the user to another page?

Have been working with QML since few days and really couldn't get much info... Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example on how to do this kind of behaviour with QML/Qt5. It uses multiple components to do all this:

1. [Grid](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-grid.html) to display all your items in a grid-like position
2. [Delegate](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#view-delegates) and [Component](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qml-qtquick2-component.html) to represent each item in the grid instead of repeating the code
3. [Keys](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-keys.html) to detect/process keyboard events
4. [MouseArea](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-mousearea.html) to handle mouse events

Here you go:

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 400
    height: 400

    // Use the Grid component to display your images
    Grid {
      id: grid;
      // You want the grid to be as big a the window so that
      // it follows the resizing
      anchors.fill: parent

      // Add spacing between images
      rowSpacing: 5
      columnSpacing: 5

      columns: 3
      rows: 3

      // Use a Repeater to repeat your images
      Repeater {
        // 5 * 5 elements here
        model: grid.columns * grid.rows;
        // Component to use to represent each image you want
        delegate: delegateGridImage
      }
    }

    // Component that will represent each Image you want in your grid.
    // Right now I use Rectangle because it is easier for an example
    Component {
      id: delegateGridImage

      Item {
        // For each Item we remember on which row and column it is
        // index is a property of each delegate in a Repeater
        // corresponding to the current index of the element
        property int currentColumn: index % grid.columns
        property int currentRow: Math.floor(index / grid.rows);

        // We want the Item to grow with the grid
        width: grid.width / grid.columns
        height: grid.height / grid.rows
        Rectangle {
          anchors.fill: parent
          color: index % 2 == 0 ? "red" : "blue"

          // Add a text to show how each Item can be different
          Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "Col " + currentColumn + " - Row " + currentRow
          }
        }

        // Add a MouseArea in each element that hide the grid when clicked
        MouseArea {
          anchors.fill: parent
          cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor
          onClicked: {
            fakeViewText.text = "The element clicked was" +
                                "[" + currentRow + "," + currentColumn + "]"
            grid.visible = false;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // Add a Text element in the middle to fake a new "view"
    // Will display which element was clicked and be hidden
    // as soon as we hit escape
    Text {
      id: fakeViewText
      // The text is visible only when the grid is not
      visible: !grid.visible
      anchors.centerIn: parent
      text: ""

      // Enable keyboard detection only if the fakeView is visible
      Keys.enabled: visible

      // Give focus to the element when visible to have keys detection
      focus: visible

      // Bring back the grid when escape is pressed
      Keys.onEscapePressed: {
        grid.visible = true;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful and well crafted answer!

Comment: @Matthew Thanks, hope this helps the OP to better understand QML!